# Websocket client?

Tags: java, android, websocket, okhttp

I am created nodejs WebSocket server using ws library.

I want to add a module to android for chatting with an administrator.

socket.js

```
const Messages = require('../models/index').Messages;

module.exports = (httpsServer) => {
    const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
    const wss = new WebSocketServer({
        server: httpsServer
    });

    wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
        console.log('connected');
        ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
            console.log('received: %s', message);
            let jsonObject = JSON.parse(message);

            switch (jsonObject.class) {
                case "userIdFromUser":
                    Messages.findAll({
                        attributes: ['message', 'roomId', 'senderId', 'createdAt'],
                        where: {
                            roomId: jsonObject.data.senderId
                        },
                        order: [
                            ['createdAt', 'ASC']
                        ]
                    }).then(message => {
                        let response = {
                            "class": "getAllMessages",
                            "data": message
                        };
                        wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
                            if (client != ws) {
                                console.log('client opened');
                                client.send(JSON.stringify(response));
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    break;
                case "messageToAdmin":
                    Messages.create({
                        roomId: jsonObject.data.senderId,
                        senderId: jsonObject.data.senderId,
                        message: jsonObject.data.message
                    }).then(message => {
                        let response = {
                            "class": "messageToUser",
                            "data": message
                        };
                        wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
                            if (client != ws) {
                                console.log('client opened');
                                client.send(JSON.stringify(response)); 
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    break;
                case "messageToUser":
                    Messages.create({
                        roomId: jsonObject.data.senderId,
                        senderId: "1", //administrator
                        message: jsonObject.data.message
                    }).then(message => {
                        let response = {
                            "class": "messageToAdmin",
                            "data": message
                        };
                        wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
                            if (client != ws) {
                                console.log('client opened');
                                client.send(JSON.stringify(response));
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
};
```

For android, I am used okhttp, nkzawa/socket.io-client, nv-websocket-client, TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket libraries to connect websocket server.

All libraries are working but only for the single user. When I connected from the second device, the messages not received.  When the user sends a message to administrator onMessage event not run.

From above libraries, okhttp are better for connection and reconnection. I tried to add forceNewConnection(true) for okhttp but I did not find a good example for this.

How can I solve the problem. Thanks for the advice ...